# Salvar a data e hora?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Queria saber como faz para salvar a data e hora no banco, sendo que a hora queria que puxasse automaticamente da maquina ou servidor. Assim eu consegui registrar a data, porem a hora fica zerada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu `ViewModel`:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public decimal Combustivel { get; set; }
public DateTime DataSaida { get; set; }
public int AutorId { get; set; }
public int NumCarroId { get; set; }
public int Km { get; set; }
```

Minha Classe `Model`:

```
public class Rota
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DataSaida { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Combustivel { get; set; }
    public virtual int Km { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Autor { get; set; }
    public virtual Veiculo NumCarro { get; set; }    
}
```

Classe DAO(Faz as inserções):

```
public void Adiciona(Rota rota)
    {
        ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
        session.Save(rota);
        tx.Commit();
    }
```

Classe Controller:

```
public ActionResult Adiciona(RotaModel viewModel)
    { 
            var rotas = ckm.Consulta(viewModel.NumCarroId);
            //  Aqui busca todas as rotas deste veículo

            var maiorRota = rotas.OrderByDescending(r => r.Km).FirstOrDefault();
            //  Aqui você tem a última rota cadastrada, considerando a regra geral  


            if (maiorRota != null && viewModel.Km < maiorRota.Km)
            // Aqui se não tiver valor para fazer comparação (maiorRota != null), ele ira registrar.
            // Ele ira fazer a comparação e ira salvar se estiver de acordo(viewModel.Km < maiorRota.Km).
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Km_Atual.Invalido",
                "A quilometragem precisa ser maior que a anterior");
            }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            Rota rota = viewModel.CriaRota();
            dao.Adiciona(rota);
            //return View();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        else
            {
            ViewBag.Usuarios = usuarioDAO.Lista();
            ViewBag.Veiculo = veiculoDAO.Lista();
            return View("Form", viewModel);
            }
    }
```

Tabela ROTA:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentou atribuir DateTime.Now para a propriedade de seu objeto ?

Comment: Não, na verdade não sei aonde colocar esse DateTime.Now, não sei se é na hora que ira registrar no banco ou quando cria-se o banco

Comment: Posta o código que faz a inserção no banco de dados. Diga tb qual é o database que vc utiliza.

Comment: No controller, faça -> `Rota rota = viewModel.CriaRota(); rota.DataSaida = DateTime.Now; dao.Adiciona(rota);`

Comment: Eu não entendi se é a data e hora ou somente a hora atual do sistema, ou seja, o usuário informa alguma data e o sistema coloca a hora atual, ou ??? bom fiquei na duvida.

Comment: Seria somente a hora, mas se pega a data atual e a hora não ha problema

Comment: @LINQ Deu certo do metodo que você explicou, poderia por como resposta para eu dar o voto

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam Farei agora

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam Pronto xD

Comment: Obrigado @LINQ denovo pela ajuda que me deu, e aos outros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você cria um objeto do tipo `Rota` logo após verificar a validade do `ModelState`. É possível *setar* a propriedade de data ali.

```
Rota rota = viewModel.CriaRota(); 
rota.DataSaida = DateTime.Now; 
dao.Adiciona(rota);
```

Answer (score 0):

Vinicius.
Você pode configurar isso direto no banco, coloque assim:

```
Campo       Tipo         Default
datasaida   timestamp   current_timestamp
```

Dessa forma o próprio banco pega a data pra você.

Testa aí e dá um feed.
Abraço

Comment: Pega a hora tambem?

Comment: Pega sim. Comigo sempre funciona. Tento dividir algumas tarefas para o banco e essa de pegar a data e hora é uma delas :)